# net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH on angular 2 on docker cloud

Tags: angular, docker, docker-cloud

I am getting a net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH  main.bundle.js  while running angular 2 on docker cloud ,the same however works on my local docker instance

The below is the docker file

```
FROM node

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . /usr/src/app

RUN npm install
```

and the docker compose

```
version: '2'
services:
app:
 build: .
 volumes:
   - ./:/usr/src/app
 ports:
   - 4200:4200
   - 49153:49153
 command: npm start
```

Any clue as to why this is happening will be of much help

Answer (score 1):

Happened to me after I updated one of the packages in **node_modules**. Probably integrity/checksum-related issue. The cure was to flush **node_modules** and run

`$ npm install`

again.